# Calculating algorithmic complexity for median smoothing in Time Series

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, time-series

If my question is not for this forum, please tell and i'll delete it.
This question more theoretically. 
A time series with `T` observations is given. Median smoothing with  width window  of `n` was applied to this series.
How can i calculate  algorithmic complexity for the most efficient algorithm for this median smoothing, depending on `T` and `n`?

Answer (score 1):

The median of $N$ elements can be obtained in linear time $O(N)$ by the median-of-medians method. So applied to every window, you achieve the complexity $O((T-N)N)$, which can be $O(TN)$.

But you can also keep the elements in a balanced binary search tree which you update incrementally. This yields a complexity $O(N\log N+(T-N)\log N)$ which can be $O(T\log N)$.

But these are just upper bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very well.

Comment: Can you asnwer me. is it possible realize this algorythm  in R. Or this question is not for this forum?

Comment: @psysky: it is certainly possible to write it in R.

Comment: where i can ask question about how to do it. Here or on stackoverflow?

Comment: @psysky: you must do it yourself and ask specific questions when you are stuck.